# T1/pplj/m/n/10=pplr9d not loadable

Tags: fonts

I apologize in advance as font missing questions floods this site, however this time I tried all I could think of and looking up online did not return a solution to the problem below.

My new laptop has a small SDD and I had to save some space, thus installed a minimal latex install in it. I have been using it for some months, but recently I decided to print out a document using the tufte-book package.

All dependencies listed in CTAN's tufte-latex were installed, but in this machine it generates an error that points to a missing font:

```
! Font T1/pplj/m/n/10=pplr9d at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not foun
d.
<to be read again>
```

Seems that pplj and pplr9d refers to the Palatino font required by the tufte-book class, mathpazo is installed and so all other dependencies of that package that are listed in [here](https://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tufte-latex/README.txt).

I ask, as I cannot find any solution either here or with google:

- How to install the missing requirement with tlmgr?

Answer (score 4):

Found the solution. One can either install collections with tlmgr or more economically:

```
sudo tlmgr install palatino mathpazo fpl
```